Triples of elements in a finite group
Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ a prime number, and let $G_p$ denote the subset $G$ consisting of $p$-power order elements. Fix conjugacy classes $A$, $B$, and $C$ in $G_p$, meaning that these are orbits for the conjugation action of $G$ on $G_p$. Fix $w\in G_p$. Do the following sets have the same number of elements:
$$\{(x,y,z)\in G^3_p \ | \ xyz=w, \ \langle x,y \rangle\subseteq G_p, \  \langle xy, z \rangle \subseteq G_p, \ x\in A, y\in B, z\in C\}$$
and
$$\{(x,y,z)\in G^3_p \  | \ xyz=w, \ \langle y,z \rangle \subseteq G_p, \   \langle x, yz \rangle \subseteq G_p, \ x\in A, y\in B, z\in C\}$$
?
I wrote in the comments where this comes from.

TeX advice: please use $\langle$ and $\rangle$ (\langle and \rangle) instead of $<$ and $>$.

thank you! fixed

Have you tried to check this on the smallest possible cases (i.e., to avoid trivial cases, the smallest groups and $p$ for which $G_p$ is not a subgroup)?

Do you have a reason to believe they should be the same, or at least a reason to hope they might be the same?

Yes I do have a reason to hope they are the same, but also worried about the possibility of counter-examples. I thought maybe it could be the kind of question that someone who works in finite group theory might immediately see how to approach.

@OrenBen-Bassat, can you tell us for which examples does it hold?

I am not sure completely, but the case that any two distinct $p$-Sylow subgroups intersect at the identity of $G$ could be a lot easier to handle.

@OrenBen-Bassat, it seems to me that looking at $S_n$ and $A_n$ for small $n$ 's are the most obvious cases to check as it is easy to identify the $p$-elements there.

will take a look at that thanks!

Basically this formula came from the "associativity" of a convolution type product on $Fun(G_p, \mathbb{C})^{G}$ given by $m(a,b)(g)=\underset{{(h,k)\in G_p^2 \ | \ hk=g, \ \langle h,k \rangle \subseteq G_p}}\sum a(h)b(k)$ which I "know" for other reasons is associative.

There's a bijection between the two sets, but only if you cycle the conjugacy classes $A$, $B$ and $C$. If $xyz=w$ then $z(z^{-1}xz)(z^{-1}yz)=w$. So your new $x$ is the old $z$, the new $y$ is the old $z^{-1}xz$ and the new $z$ is the old $z^{-1}yz$. Note that $\langle z^{-1}xz,z^{-1}yz\rangle$ is conjugate to $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\langle z,(z^{-1}xz)(z^{-1}yz)\rangle$ is conjugate to $\langle xy,z\rangle$.
If you don't cycle the conjugacy classes, the statement is not true.
A counterexample is given by $G=A_6$, the alternating group of degree six, with $A=B$ the conjugacy class of the permutation $(1,2,3)(4,5,6)$ and $C$ the conjugacy class of the permutation $(1,2,3)$. Let $g=(1,2,3)$. Then the first set has size $44$ and the second has size $8$. I did the computation in Magma.
While I was writing this Derek Holt posted a smaller example.

But then you also need to switch $A,B,C$ around

Ah yes, I didn't notice that. Whoops. In that case it's probably not true.

Thanks very much, I somehow see your answer only today. That is the reason I am only responding now.

That's because I hid it, after @user49822 pointed out that the conjugacy classes needed cycling in my original response. Which was roughly the first paragraph.

I did the calculation with $G=A_4$, $p=3$, $w=(1,2,3)$, $A=B=(1,2,3)^G$, $C=(1,3,2)^G$, and the sizes of the two sets were $1$ and $4$, but someone should check this.

Yes this is correct. A similar thing works in every group of the form $N\rtimes C_3$ where $N$ has order coprime to $3$ and $C_3$ acts nontrivially. There are then 3 conjugacy classes $A^{\pm 1}$ of elements of order $3$. Choose $w\in A$, $B=A$, $C=A^{-1}$, $p=3$. Then the sizes are $1$ and $|A|$, namely the first set is the singleton ${(w,w,w^{-1})}$ and the second is ${(w,a,a^{-1}):a\in A}$.

Perfect thanks!
